# Submit image via AjaxForm and perform callback

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have the following function

```
(inside onchange; console.log works well)
$("#prof_picture").ajaxForm(
        {

        target: '#preview',
        success: function(response){

            console.log("called");

        }
});
```

The success function is not called and therefore no feedback is received. Feedback is echoed in the following way `"{message:"success",action:"something",data:Array}"`. Can someone help me please? Thank you very much

Here is the form

```
<form id="profile_picture_upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="profile/uploadProfilePicture.php" method="post" name="prof_picture">
   <input id="profpic1" style="display:none;" name="profile_picture" type="file">
   <a id="change_profile_picture" class="profile_option" onclick="$('#profpic1').click();">Upload</a>
</form>
```

Comment: Look at your browser's developer tools. Look at the JavaScript console. Does it report any errors? Look at the Net tab. Is the request being made? Does it get a response? Do they contain the data you expect? If `success` isn't called then add `error` and examine the arguments it gets passed.

Comment: Not much to go on here, but since it sounds like you're trying to upload a file did you include ` enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your `<form>`?

Comment: @Quentin nothing is called...

Comment: @AndreCalenta — Having seen your updated code, I don't understand why you think the Ajax routine should be called. You never submit the form.

Answer (score 1):

As Quentin mentioned, the form isn't submitting.

Bind the ajax to the correct form ID instead of the name of the form

```
$("#profile_picture_upload").ajaxForm(
    {

    target: '#preview',
    success: function(response){

        console.log("called");

    }
});
```

And use this html to submit the form

```
<form id="profile_picture_upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="profile/uploadProfilePicture.php" method="post" name="prof_picture">
   <input id="profpic1" style="display:none;" name="profile_picture" type="file" onchange="$('#profile_picture_upload').submit();">
   <a id="change_profile_picture" class="profile_option" onclick="$('#profpic1').click();">Upload</a>
</form>
```

though it'll click through to the next page if you do this, so you probably want to add the return false to prevent it from leaving this page.